# How do I do MySQL queries on an RDS instance from an EC2 instance?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I've been trying to set up a system where my database will be in an AWS RDS instance and my programs in a EC2 instance (seemingly very straightforward)

For some reason following the results [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html) have been pretty unhelpful.

To clarify, what I'm looking for is some sample code to connect to a db and run mysql queries. So far my every attempt ends with my program trying to connect with my localhost mysql on my ec2 instance despite specifying the rds url.

Here's my script,

```
<?php
$servername = "maindb.gibberish.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_error($conn)) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}else{
        echo "connected successfully";    
}
?>
```

Comment: Show your database connection code so we can see what you are doing wrong. By the way, this is EXTREMELY standard stuff that you should be able to find thousands of examples of if you do a Google search for something like "PHP connect to remote MySQL database".

Comment: Yeah I did that. The problem seems to be actually querying the database. I can connect fine in CLI but just not from a php script.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Do you have the correct hostname? And have you given the RDS the correct security group rules? AWS blocks all incoming connections by default. The mysql port is 3306.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code in my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139268/when-creating-a-database-in-mysql-with-php-using-the-following-code-where-does-w/35139496#35139496) which also explains what each line of code does.  You would type your amazon RDS **endpoint** in the `$servername` variable. and also change your query in the `$sql` variable.

In terms of ensuring that your RDS can be contacted by your EC2 Server. you need to ensure that the security group is correctly set to allow connections from your server. like so:

**1. In your EC2 Management Console, select 'Security Groups' from the left side navigation.**
[image: Fig1]

**2. Select the security group for your RDS server**.
n.b. If you didn't name this something specific when you set it up then the name is likely to look like `rds-launch-wizard created xxxxxxx`.
[image: Fig2]

Click the edit button. It is likely that the IP address which is in there, is the one which you are working from. (Or the one which you were on when you setup the server).  You need to change this to either ANY, or just your EC2 server's public IP address.

EDIT: after looking at your code I think you are testing the connection incorrectly.

```
<?php
$servername = "maindb.gibberish.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {

    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));

}else{
        echo "connected successfully";

}


?>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, 

I tried your solution in the link, but as I mentioned I am not trying to connect to my localhost. I replaced servername with maindb.gibberish.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com and changed the username and password appropriately but I don't get anything in output except that 
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /var/www/serverfunctions/test_mysqli.php on line 7
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/serverfunctions/test_mysqli.php on line 10

Which I believe indicates that the attempt to connect failed.

Comment: Done. Please let me know if you have any ideas :L

Comment: Have you checked the guide to what I put regarding the amazon security group settings? After checking my example code in the other answer again it appears you are correct about it not connecting. And this indiciates that your amazon RDS server isn't accessible. And so you should check the security group settings.

Comment: The security group allows connections from all IP's to port 3306. The only thing i'm not sure of is how to specify which port to connect to.

Comment: it will connect to port 3306 by default.

Comment: hang on I think I have spotted something your code example, I will post in my answer

Comment: hmmm.. yes you are correct. That does make more sense. Unfortunately it does not appear to have resolved the timeout issue..

I'm thinking it must be something to do with how I am accessing the database. Same exact script works to access my localhost mysql

Comment: Hmm, seems strange. Does your EC2 instance have permission for outgoing 3306 connections? both in security groups (which is usually open to all by default anyway), and in the windows or linux firewall

Comment: Nevermind. It was in fact a security group problem. Thank you for all your help.